# Fastest / most elegant method for looping through a range to find values in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find

Good day,

In my project, I encounter a number of situations in which I need my code to find a certain string multiple times in a given range, and do a number of actions when this string is found.

I have written a `Do..Loop` which suits my needs, but since I am not the most elegant programmer (I am self-taught) I am wondering about other methods that may be faster or perhaps more elegant.

Example code:

```
Set FindStr = .Sheets(c).Range("C2:C" & LRow).Find("MANUALLY", lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not FindStr is Nothing Then
    FRow = FindStr.Row
End If

Do While Not FindStr Is Nothing
    If FindStr.Offset(0,2) = "SA" Then
        FindStr.Offset(0,5) = "Confirmed"
    End If
    Set FindStr = .Sheets(c).Range("C2:C" & LRow).Find("MANUALLY", after:=FindStr, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not FindStr Is Nothing Then
        If FindStr.Row = FRow then Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. These questions are better to ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue an search, you can use `FindNext` rather than restart a new search.

The only thing you need to be aware of is that `FindNext` will continue a search at the top once it is done. To be able to tell that the search starts again, you save the address of the first match and if `FindNext` returns you the address of your first match you know that you are done.

One remark to your variable naming: `Find/FindNext` return `Ranges`, and you should gibe your variable a name that reflects that. `FindStr` impplies that it holds a string, which is not true. The *default property* of a Range is the value of it, so it may look as if it is a string - but it isn't.

Have a look at this piece of code:

```
Const searchStr = "MANUALLY"
With .Sheets(c).Range("C2:C" & LRow)
    Dim findRange As Range, firstHit As Range
    Set findRange = .Find(searchStr, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
        Set firstHit = findRange     ' Remember first hit.
        Do
            ' ... (Do your stuff here)
            Set findRange = .FindNext(findRange)
        Loop While Not findRange Is Nothing And findRange.Address <> firstHit.Address
    Else
        ' in case you didn't find anything
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Won't `Loop While Not findRange Is Nothing And findRange.Address <> firstHit.Address` return an error if the string wasn't found? Or won't this happen since FindNext will return from the top? I learned to avoid this since it caused a lot of errors initially for me. I also started to avoid `.FindNext` after I discovered it would sometimes not find anything or find the wrong values whereas setting a new Find would work. Although, the latter may as well be a result of my incompetence.

Comment: The `If Not FindRange is Nothing` after the initial `Find` will prevent a runtime error - it will jump directly to the `Else`. I would recommend to step thru the code using the debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, it would after the first search. Were it to find nothing at a following search, then that line would return an error on `findRange.Address`. But since you mentioned `.FindNext` will search back from the top, I don't think this will ever occur... Correct? Unless I were to delete the line the first result is located of course.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The check for `findRange Is Nothing` as condition in the loop is superfluous - except if the code would overwrite all found values, and then you would get an runtime error.