# Loop, find cells with value then search column for the same cell and change its value

Tags: excel, vba

### Detailed Problem

I'm attempting to write a VBA code that would loop through Column D,

if it finds Cells(i,"D")  = "Good" then the code would search the entire column D for that value in cells (i,"D") and change all it's value to "Good"

---

Here is an Image on before the code.

[image]

Here is an Image after the code.

[image]

My Attempt:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Rows.Count


If Cells(i, "m") = "Good" Then

x = Cells(i, "m")

Next i
```

I think you would have to store the value ( ID Number ) and then search for it which I assigned "X". Once "X" is found change the status to "Good"

Comment: Where's your attempt at changing the values?

Comment: Should we believe your narrative, your images or your code for column identification? They are all different.

Comment: @user11246173 look at the image.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I'm not asking for the solution but pointers on what to study/learn to take the next step. I'm stuck.

Comment: Assign the ID to a variable, and then use a `Do While...Loop` together with the `Find` function to look for the ID's in col D.  Here's a good loop method to find the the ID's: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157814/fastest-most-elegant-method-for-looping-through-a-range-to-find-values-in-exce

Comment: My first advice is to sort this by both ID and Status first. You could write a much faster code for sorted data than for unsorted. • Is it possible to sort your data?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  Sorting the data is sadly not an option. The data is simply too large and has too many variables.

Comment: @TimStack Thank you, I will learn about the functions and give the question an analysis and attempt to apply it here.

Comment: @User1932s Especially if your data is large it will be extremely slow **without** sorting! Your arguments against sorting are not really comprehensible. Please re-think if sorting the data is really not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an AutoFilter

```
Option Explicit

Sub makeGood()

    Dim i As Long, tmp As Variant
    Dim dict As Object, k As Variant

    'late bind a dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("sheet11")

        'remove any existing autofilters
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False

        'collect values from column D
        tmp = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value

        'build dictionary of unique ID NUMs
        For i = LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1)
            dict.Item(tmp(i, 1)) = vbNullString
        Next i

        'work with D:G range
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))

            'loop through unique ID NUMs
            For Each k In dict.Keys

                'autofilter on key
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=k, visibledropdown:=False
                'autofilter on Good
                .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="good", visibledropdown:=False

                'check for visible cells
                If Application.Subtotal(103, .Offset(1, 0).Cells) > 0 Then

                    'remove the Good autofilter
                    .AutoFilter field:=4

                    'step down off the header and put Good in the filtered cells
                    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 3)
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = "Good"
                    End With

                End If

                'clear autofilter
                .AutoFilter field:=1
                .AutoFilter field:=4

            Next k

        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It WORKS!!! I genuinely can not thank you enough. This is amazing thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit convoluted, but here is an idea.

```
Sub f(strSearchFor as string)

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary

Set r = Range("a1:b10")

For Each c In r.Columns(2).Cells

    If StrComp(c.Value, strSearchFor, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

        If Not d.Exists(c.Value) Then
            d.Add c.Offset(0, -1).Value, c.Value
        End If

    End If

Next c

For Each c In r.Columns(1).Cells

    If d.Exists(c.Value) Then
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = d(c.Value)
    End If

Next c


Set r = Nothing
Set d = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Nathan, I tested your code, it's simply not running. No errors or anything. But it does ask me to name the macro. I'm not sure as to how to move forward.

Comment: Hi, did you modify the code to suit your needs?  Worksheet name, and the range `Range("a1:b10")` ??  You would run like so, in VBA, `f("Good")` for example.  "
  

  


@Nathan_Sav I'm not asking for the solution but pointers on what to study/learn to take the next step. I'm stuck"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a helper column and do it with a formula only:

Add the following formula eg. in H2 (of your example) and pull it down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,G:G,"Good")>0,"Good",G2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub trst()

        Dim i As Long, y As Long, LastRow As Long
        Dim ID As String, Status As String

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change Workbook / Sheet names

            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 2 To LastRow

                ID = .Range("D" & i).Value
                Status = .Range("G" & i).Value

                For y = 2 To LastRow

                    If ID = .Range("D" & y).Value Then
                        .Range("G" & y).Value = Status
                    End If

                Next y

            Next i

        End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Test with arrais. With arrais it is much faster

```
Option Explicit

Sub Subst()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim ArrayColumnD As Variant
        ArrayColumnD = .Range("D1:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
        Dim ArrayColumnG As Variant
        ArrayColumnG = .Range("G1:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row)

        Dim ID As String
        Dim RowActual As Long
        Dim RowTest As Long
        For RowActual = 2 To UBound(ArrayColumnD)
            If ArrayColumnG(RowActual, 1) = "Good" Then
                ID = ArrayColumnD(RowActual, 1)
                For RowTest = 2 To UBound(ArrayColumnD)
                    If ArrayColumnD(RowTest, 1) = ID Then
                        ArrayColumnG(RowTest, 1) = "Good"
                    End If
                Next RowTest
            End If
        Next RowActual

        .Range("G1:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row) = ArrayColumnG
    End With
End Sub
```