# Never ending Do While...Loop VBA Word

Tags: vba, while-loop, ms-word, ms-office

I'm trying to count the number of words highlighted in yellow/green/grey OR in blue. The search part is working well but I noticed that when the last highlighted range is in a table, the Do While...Loop never ends and makes Word crash... Any idea why this could happen?

I also tried with a While...Wend but same problem. And only for this particular case! Otherwise the whole code works fine.

```
'Find all highlighted text
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Wrap = wdFindStop 'until end of doc
    .Highlight = True

'If highlight color is blue add to w_blueMatch, else add to w_yellowGreenGreyMatch
    Do While .Execute(Forward:=True)
        If .Found Then
            Set o_tempRange = Selection.Range
            If o_tempRange.Hyperlinks.count > 0 Then
                For Each o_link In o_tempRange.Hyperlinks
                    o_link.Delete
                Next o_link
            End If
            If o_tempRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise Then
                w_blueMatch = w_blueMatch + o_tempRange.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
            Else
                w_yellowGreenGreyMatch = w_yellowGreenGreyMatch + o_tempRange.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End With
```

(I had the same problem for hyperlinks... That's why I delete them...)
Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA in Word but it would seem you're not testing if Find returns anything.. Maybe [structure your loop like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55158371/10540017)

Comment: This has come up before. See my Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51932924/3077495

Comment: @Pookye May I ask you to add your `Find` so i can reproduce